# SQL help, can't get the desired output with joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.team_flag AS flag_1, 
    t2.team_flag AS flag_2, 
    t1.team_name AS team_name_1, 
    t2.team_name AS team_name_2, 
    t1.team_id AS team_id_1, 
    t2.team_id AS team_id_2, 
    games.game_id, 
    games.game_team_1, 
    games.game_team_2, 
    games.game_time, 
    games.game_day, 
    games.game_location, 
    games.game_group, 
    games.game_active, 
    location_id_to_names.location_id, 
    location_id_to_names.location_name 
FROM games 
    LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.team_id = game_team_1 
    LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.team_id = game_team_2 
    LEFT JOIN location_id_to_names ON games.game_location = location_id_to_names.location_id
ORDER BY games.game_day
```

Which returns all games with all team names correct, however, I now want to select only ONE game with a specific ID, an this doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.team_flag AS flag_1, 
    t2.team_flag AS flag_2, 
    t1.team_name AS team_name_1, 
    t2.team_name AS team_name_2, 
    t1.team_id AS team_id_1, 
    t2.team_id AS team_id_2, 
    games.game_id, 
    games.game_team_1, 
    games.game_team_2, 
    games.game_time, 
    games.game_day, 
    games.game_location, 
    games.game_group, 
    games.game_active, 
    location_id_to_names.location_id, 
    location_id_to_names.location_name 
FROM games 
    LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.team_id = game_team_1 AND games.game_id = :game_id 
    LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.team_id = game_team_2 
    LEFT JOIN location_id_to_names ON games.game_location = location_id_to_names.location_id 
ORDER BY games.game_day
```

(:game_id) gets parsed by PDO.

This is what I get as the output:

[image]
The ID is correct in the highlighted row, but it isn't the first row, I need this to be the first row, as I want to limit the search to 1 result, so I don't want a row filled with null values.

What's the best way to get this done?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. That said, you could try ordering by "flag_1 IS NULL"

Comment: I don't really understand. You have to add a `LIMIT` clause to obtain only 1 result ; but if you want only the second line of your example, you'll have to think to a `WHERE field IS NOT NULL` clause also.

Comment: Remove `LEFT` from your joins - you don't need it - all you need is a straight join.

Answer (score 0):

Move games.game_id = :game_id to WHERE statement

```
SELECT 
    t1.team_flag AS flag_1, 
    t2.team_flag AS flag_2, 
    t1.team_name AS team_name_1, 
    t2.team_name AS team_name_2, 
    t1.team_id AS team_id_1, 
    t2.team_id AS team_id_2, 
    games.game_id, 
    games.game_team_1, 
    games.game_team_2, 
    games.game_time, 
    games.game_day, 
    games.game_location, 
    games.game_group, 
    games.game_active, 
    location_id_to_names.location_id, 
    location_id_to_names.location_name 
FROM games 
    LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.team_id = game_team_1
    LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.team_id = game_team_2 
    LEFT JOIN location_id_to_names ON games.game_location = location_id_to_names.location_id 
WHERE
    games.game_id = :game_id 
ORDER BY games.game_day
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LEFT` from your joins and leave a simple `JOIN` in place:

```
SELECT 
    t1.team_flag AS flag_1, 
    t2.team_flag AS flag_2, 
    t1.team_name AS team_name_1, 
    t2.team_name AS team_name_2, 
    t1.team_id AS team_id_1, 
    t2.team_id AS team_id_2, 
    games.game_id, 
    games.game_team_1, 
    games.game_team_2, 
    games.game_time, 
    games.game_day, 
    games.game_location, 
    games.game_group, 
    games.game_active, 
    location_id_to_names.location_id, 
    location_id_to_names.location_name 
FROM games 
    LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.team_id = game_team_1 AND games.game_id = :game_id 
    LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.team_id = game_team_2 
    LEFT JOIN location_id_to_names ON games.game_location = location_id_to_names.location_id 
ORDER BY games.game_day
```

The `LEFT` part is responsible for joining the row you want against all other rows with the same team.